# Specify WebApi to use only Route when matches request

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have an .NET WebApi which has `[Route("file/{fileId}")]`

The question is why the following Uri matches this route:

```
http://localhost:52052/file/Info?fileId=4eb335ac-dc6b-4fd9-a6e1-1ca83d931b77
```

The default route is:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: can you post the code from controller..?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about routing in `Web API 2` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), there is a section about **Route Constraints** with good examples.

> why the following Uri matches this route:

The answer depends on how your action method looks like.

For example, if it is like this:

```
[Route("file/{fileId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string fileId)
```

then `/file/Info?fileId=4eb335ac-dc6b-4fd9-a6e1-1ca83d931b77` **will match** this route and value of `fileId` will be equal to `"Info"`

if it is like this:

```
[Route("file/{fileId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid fileId)
```

then `/file/Info?fileId=4eb335ac-dc6b-4fd9-a6e1-1ca83d931b77` **will not match** this route, but `/file/4eb335ac-dc6b-4fd9-a6e1-1ca83d931b77` **will match**

Comment: My action method looks like this:
    `[Route("file/{fileId}")]

    [HttpGet]

    public HttpResponseMessage Open(string fileId)

    {

    }`

All the things you say are true, but I still can't find out why 
`http://localhost:52052/file/info?fileId=3c70859e-68a3-40e3-bebb-09f89b3ac257` goes to the Open action with valid fileId as param.